# No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: arm-linux-androideabi when build flutter project

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I did not compile my flutter project for a while, today when I compile the project on macOS Big Sur in Android Studio Arctic Fox, shows error like this:

```
> No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: arm-linux-androideabi
```

I am searching from google, someone said the plugin version should greater than `3.2.1`, I check my `com.android.tools.build:gradle` version and all greater than `3.2.1`.
[image]

I also tried to delete the `build` folder and `pubspec.lock` file, still did not fix it. any other suggestion for this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

downgrade NDK to `NDK 20.1.5948944` fix this problem, more details:https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/76393.